# Sending raw data using TCP/IP in Linux

Tags: linux, telnet, netcat, tcp

i have to send byte array using TCP/IP in Linux. Which program should i use? I couldn't use netcat because program gives me an error about authorization. I can send data through telnet but i can't use telnet to send raw data.

Comment: Can you please include the authorization error from netcat?

Comment: What kind of "authorization" error is that? netcat should work out of box for every user as long you do not need to bind local port < 1024

Comment: netcat is giving me an error "host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is not authoritative". I can't send raw to a TCP server via port 1234. I can send string to TCP server by using telnet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `netcat` to send raw data. If it's giving you an error about authorization any other alternatives will probably do the same; I'm guessing the error comes from the host you're trying to connect to.

Please try to post more information (the actual error) and the options you're passing to netcat.

Comment: netcat is giving me an error "host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is not authoritative". I can't send raw to a TCP server via port 1234. I can send string to TCP server by using telnet.

Comment: What is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx? Is it the host you're running netcat in?

Comment: I have a TCP listener at IP: 192.168.10.28 Port: 1234. I can send string data from another computer in Windows using telnet, putty vs also i can send data in linux using telnet but i can't send raw data using netcat.

Comment: @petre: please post the actual commands you're using and the messages you're getting.